# ASP MS-SQL server 2008 connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Hi i am trying to connect to MS-SQLSERVER-2008 from asp. when i am running the asp page. i am getting this error

Error:

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
```

What is the cause for this error.
and is anything wrong in my code causing this error?

code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Dim Connection
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Connection.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=products;UID=sa;PWD=sa","sa","sa"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.products_images"
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection;
If Recordset.EOF Then
Response.Write("No records returned.")
Else
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
Response.write Recordset("ID")
Response.write Recordset("product_id")
Response.write Recordset("im_name")
Response.write Recordset("im_type")
Response.write "<br>"   
Recordset.MoveNext    
Loop
End If
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

when i add below line, i am getting error.

```
Connection.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=products;UID=sa;PWD=sa","sa","sa"
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: on which line you get error?

Comment: @AshReva pls check the post, i have updated it.

Comment: what is this "PWD=sa","sa","sa" in your connection string? Is this your password?

Comment: try Connection.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=products;UID=sa;PWD=sa"

Comment: remove last two `"sa"` from the connection string and then try.

Comment: Tried but still not working...

Comment: Try Connection.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=products;UID=sa;PWD=sa;Trusted_Connection=No"

Comment: could you try using this driver SQL Server Native Client 10.0 instead of using just SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the express version of SQL Server?  If you are you need to put "\SQLEXPRESS" after the server name - eg `"Server=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=..."`

You're using an ODBC connection string, which should work, but with SqlServer 2008 you would be better off looking at Native Client 10 or even OLEDB - see the links below

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/

http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Dim Connection
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Connection.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=products;UID=sa;PWD=sa"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.products_images"
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

If Recordset.EOF Then
If Recordset.EOF Then
Response.Write("No records returned.")
Else
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
Response.write Recordset("Dept_Id")
Response.write Recordset("Dept_Name")
Response.write "<br>"   
Recordset.MoveNext    
Loop
End If
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some text in answer to explain how this answer solve current issue and helpful for others